# How to use PreventDefault in AspNetCore?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a bootstrap modal which allow to the user to update some information of his account. Actually I want keep the modal open when the form is submitted, because if the user submit the form then the modal for default will be closed by the page refresh.

For doing so I added the following form inside the modal:

```
@model Demo.ViewModels.UserProfileViewModel;

<form asp-controller="User" asp-action="UpdateUser" asp-antiforgery="true" id="userInformations">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="User.Email" value="@Model.User.Email" />
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="User.??" type="password" value="?" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Update</button>
</div>
```

where `UserViewModel` is the object which contains the fields to update.

For prevent the modal closing I created a javascript function with the following content:

```
$('#userInformations').on("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
        url: "some url",
        type: "POST",
        data: some data,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result)
        }
    });
});
```

I'm stucked on the `ajax` part, in particular I need to call the method `UpdateUser` available in the `User` controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult UpdateUser(UserProfileViewModel updateUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            updateUser = _repo.UpdateUser(updateUser);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Profile");
    }
```

the main problem is: I have no idea of how to do this, and I actually didn't found anything related, so I don't know if this is possible or maybe the situation is more simple than this.

**UPDATE**

As suggested:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: "POST",
        data: this.serialize,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(true);
            console.log(result)
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have is fine. For the URL, just use `this.action`. For the data, use `this.serialize()`.

Comment: ok, but the ajax request fall in the error function, should I return a different type from the `UpdateUser` against `IActionResult`? The status of `data` contains 400